# Play with Div using jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to move specific div to up on the up link. Same as to move div to down on the 
down link. As shown in screenshot, same as i want to insert div before specific div on the
'IB' link. I want to insert div after specific div on the 'IA' link. To delete specific div on the 'D' link.

[alt text http://freeimagehosting.in/images/204_screen_j.jpg](http://freeimagehosting.in/images/204_screen_j.jpg)
[screenshot](http://freeimagehosting.in/images/204_screen_j.jpg)

Now of course there will be many alternatives are available to achieve above features like jquery, normal javascript, etc.

But I would like to know that which will be the best way to achieve this.

Any feedback would be highly appreciated...!

**EDIT : screenshot link is up now !!**

Comment: screenshot image is inaccessible

Comment: Your screenshot isn't at the posted URL, making the question very confusing without it :)

Comment: Would be nice if you could comment/mark as answer on whichever of the below helped you.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery definately makes this sort of thing a bunch easier.

Given this simple markup:

```
<div class="moveable" id="div1">
    One
    <a href='#' class="up">Move up</a>
    <a href='#' class="down">Move down</a><br/>
</div>
<div class="moveable" id="div2">
    Two
    <a href='#' class="up">Move up</a>
    <a href='#' class="down">Move down</a><br/>
</div>
<div class="moveable" id="div3">
    Three
    <a href='#' class="up">Move up</a>
    <a href='#' class="down">Move down</a><br/>
</div>
```

This jQuery will move an element up or down:

```
$('.moveable a.up').live('click',function(){
    var $div = $(this).parent('.moveable');
    var idx = $div.index();
    if(idx>0){          
        $div.remove();
        $('div.moveable:eq(' + (idx-1) +')').before($div);
    }
    return false;
});
$('.moveable a.down').live('click',function(){
    var $div = $(this).parent('.moveable');
    var idx = $div.index();
    if(idx<$('div.moveable').length-1){         
        $div.remove();
        $('div.moveable:eq(' + idx +')').after($div);
    }
    return false;
});
```

That should give you enough to go on to start doing an insert too.

Here's the fiddle if you want a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5hF98/

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [Jquery-UI Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) code, it may not be exactly what you need, but it is an option.